# what's wrong with my label update selection

Tags: d3.js, updates

I've got a bar chart which I update by clicking on the row of an associated table. Everything working perfectly fine except for the label. Here is the following code :

```
 var mytext = svg.selectAll(".text").data(filterdata,function(d) { return d.date; }) 
    mytext.enter().append("text")
    mytext.exit().remove()
    mytext
    .attr("class","label")
    .attr("x", (function(d) { return x(d.date)  }  ))
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.articles) + 1; })
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.articles; })
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    }
```

The enter selection work fine (every time I click on a new row, new label pop-up) however the old one doesn't disappear. My data set looks something like this :

```
[{articles: 1
date:Tue Apr 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
key:"2016-04-26T05:00:00.000Z"
values:1},
{articles:1
date:Thu Apr 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
key:"2016-04-28T05:00:00.000Z"
values:1},
{articles:2
date:Sun May 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
key:"2016-05-08T05:00:00.000Z"
values:2},
{etc...}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I find the solution with the following code

```
var mytext = svg.selectAll("text.label").data(filterdata,function(d) { return d.date; })
    mytext.exit().remove()
    mytext.enter().append("text")
    mytext
    .attr("class","label")
    .attr("x", (function(d) { return x(d.date)  }  ))
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.articles) + 1; })
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.articles; })
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    }
```

I change the `svg.selectAll("text")` for `svg.selectAll("text.label")`. I guess there is something related to `attr("class","label")` and `append("text")`. But I don't fully understand it if someone can explain me this :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you move the exit instruction:

```
mytext.exit().remove();
```

Before your enter instruction

```
mytext.enter().append("text")
```

Something like this

```
var mytext = svg.selectAll(".text").data(filterdata,function(d) { return d.date; })
    mytext.exit().remove();
    mytext.enter().append("text");
    mytext
    .attr("class","label")
    .attr("x", (function(d) { return x(d.date)  }  ))
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.articles) + 1; })
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.articles; })
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but hum... that doesn't change anything... :/. the thing I really don't get is why my update pattern works for my bar chart but not for the label. it's basically the same no ?